solving partial differential equation of 2 variables - particular part of the solution
I'm trying to solve the differential equation:
$a \frac{\partial u}{\partial t } = b \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2} - G$
with B.C.:
$u(z=0) = 0, u(z=1) = cos(t)$
and I want to find the solution where $t \rightarrow \infty$ so initial conditions aren't affecting the solution.
I have solved the homogenous part of the equation with homogenous boundary conditions (which I found is decreasing to 0 as t goes to infinity), and I'm struggling to find a particular solution to it.
I tried a solution of the form:
$ u(z,t) = \theta(z) + \psi(z)cos(t)$ but I couldn't reach a proper solution.
would love any help, thanks in advance.

There is still missing an IC like $u(z,0)=z$ or something similar.

OP is searching for an asymptotic or steady-state solution so the IC shouldn't matter, but it is not clear to me that one exists because of the constant nonhomogeneous term

Perhaps try a solution of the form $u(z,t) = \theta(z) + \psi_1(z)\cos(t) + \psi_2(z)\sin(t)$.

Perhaps this helps: MSE_Q4967961

Is G a constant?

a,b,G constants yes

There might be a more elegant way to do it but something that works for sure is to make an Ansatz via trigonometric functions. (This is a standard procedure for heat-equation like PDEs).
$$
u(z,t)=z\cos(t)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty g_n(t)\sin(n\pi z)
$$
Observe that the term $z\cos(t)$ handles the boundary condition and thus it makes sense to develop the remainder in a series of sine functions. (with homogenous dirichlet boundary conditions)
Now, inserting in the PDE, multiplying by $\sin(m\pi z)$ and integrating over $0\leq z\leq1$ yields
$$
\frac{1}{2m\pi}(m^3\pi^3bg_m(t)+g_m'(t)am\pi+2(-1)^m\sin(t)a+2G(-1)^m+2G)=0
$$
This ODE can be easily solved to
$$
g_n(t)=C_ne^\frac{-n^2\pi^2bt}{a}+\frac{2G((-1)^n-1)}{\pi^3bn^3}+\cos(t)\frac{2(-1)^na^2}{\pi n(\pi^4b^2n^4+a^2)}+\sin(t)\frac{2\pi(-1)^{1+n}abn}{\pi^4b^2n^4+a^2}$$
Now the remaining constants $C_n$ could be used to fit the initial condition but since you are only interested in the asymptotic behaviour we just omit those exponentially decreasing terms and end up with the (somewaht clunky) series representation of the desired solution:
$$
u(z,t)=z\cos(t)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(n\pi z)\left(\frac{2G((-1)^n-1)}{\pi^3bn^3}+\cos(t)\frac{2(-1)^na^2}{\pi n(\pi^4b^2n^4+a^2)}+\sin(t)\frac{2\pi(-1)^{1+n}abn}{\pi^4b^2n^4+a^2}\right)
$$

I'm missing a closing bracket here: $\frac{2G((-1)^n-1\color{red}{)}}{\pi^3 b n^3}$

You are correct, thanks for the hint!

Assume a solution of the form
$$
u(z,t) = \theta(z) + \phi(z)\cos(t) + \psi(z)\sin(t).
$$
Substituting into the equation and boundary conditions results in
$$
\theta''(z) = G, \qquad b\phi''(z) = a\psi(z), \qquad b\psi''(z) = -a\phi(z),
$$
$$
(\theta, \phi, \psi)|_{z=0} = (0, 0, 0), \qquad (\theta, \phi, \psi)|_{z=1} = (0, 1, 0).
$$
These are now all boundary value problems.  The solution for $\theta$ is
$$
\theta = \frac{G}{2}z(z-1).
$$
You can combine the equations for $\psi$ and $\phi$ to get a single fourth order BVP, e.g.
$$
\phi'''' + 4k^4\phi = 0, \qquad k = \sqrt{\frac{a}{2b}}.
$$
The general solution of this equation is
$$
\phi = c_1\cosh(kz)\cos(kz) + c_2\cosh(kz)\sin(kz) + c_3\sinh(kz)\cos(kz) + c_4\sinh(kz)\sin(kz),
$$
and the corresponding $\psi$ is
$$
\psi = c_4\cosh(kz)\cos(kz) - c_3\cosh(kz)\sin(kz) + c_2\sinh(kz)\cos(kz) - c_1\sinh(kz)\sin(kz).
$$
Applying the boundary conditions then gives $c_1 = c_4 = 0$, and
$$
c_2\cosh(k)\sin(k) + c_3\sinh(k)\cos(k) = 1, \qquad c_2\sinh(k)\cos(k) - c_3\cosh(k)\sin(k) = 0.
$$
Solving for $c_2$ and $c_3$ gives
$$
c_2 = \frac{\cosh(k)\sin(k)}{\cosh^2k\sin^2(k) + \sinh^2(k)\cos^2(k)}, \qquad c_3 = \frac{\sinh(k)\cos(k)}{\cosh^2(k)\sin^2(k) + \sinh^2(k)\cos^2(k)}.
$$
Assemble into solution for $u(z,t)$.
